# onfocusout check if the active element classlist contains('somthing')

Tags: javascript

i have a simple code for a dropdown menue
i made a code to remove classlist("active") from "menu" so it will disapear when i focusout it
but i want to incase i entered into input text class"inputText"   to write anything  it keep classlist("active") on  else i want to remove classlist("active")

here is my snippet code

```js
const input = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
const menue = document.querySelectorAll(".menu");
// open menue

input.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    menue[index].classList.toggle("active");
  });
});

// hide menue

input.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
    menue[index].classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  width: 180px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  border: blue;
  background-color: lightgray;
  z-index: 1;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="search_input">
              <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="search">
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
              <input type="text" class="inputText">
              <p>html</p>
              <p>CSS</p>
              <p>js</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="search_input">
              <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="search">
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
              <input type="text" class="inputText">
              <p>html</p>
              <p>CSS</p>
              <p>js</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
  </table>
  <button id="add-row">add new row</button>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't enter anything into `inputText`, because moving the mouse there makes it disappear.